# ESLint throw errors on included tsconfig file

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have the following repository structure:

`cypress` folder

- `.eslintrc.js`
- `tsconfig.json`
- `basic.spec.ts`

`src` folder

`.eslintrc.js`

`tsconfig.base.json`

`tsconfig.json`

My intention is to set the root `tsconfig.json` only for the `src` folder, and same goes for `.eslintrc.js`. Then I try to configure `tsconfig.json` and `.eslintrc.js` as well for the `cypress` folder. But I get the following error when running ESLint:

```
Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: cypress\basic.spec.ts.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided.eslint
```

here some snippets of the configuration files:

`tsconfig.base.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "incremental": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@/containers/*": ["src/components/containers/*"],
            "@/layout/*": ["src/components/layout/*"],
            "@/ui/*": ["src/components/ui/*"],
            "@/utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
            "@/images/*": ["public/images/*"],
            "@/models/*": ["src/models/*"],
            "@/data/*": ["src/data/*"],
            "@/hooks/*": ["src/hooks/*"]
        },
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./@types"]
    }
}
```

`tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
    "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "tests/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

`.eslintrc.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2021: true,
    },
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'next/core-web-vitals',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:import/typescript',
        'prettier',
    ],
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true,
        },
        ecmaVersion: 12,
        project: 'tsconfig.json',
        sourceType: 'module',
    },
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'unused-imports', 'react-hooks', 'node'],
};
```

`cypress/tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "types": ["cypress"]
    },
    "include": ["../node_modules/cypress", "./**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": []
}
```

`cypress/.eslintrc.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        es2021: true,
    },
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:import/typescript',
        'prettier',
    ],
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 12,
        project: './tsconfig.json',
        sourceType: 'module',
    },
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'unused-imports', 'node'],
};
```

So I don't understand why I got the error, because the `basic.spec.ts` is included in the `cypress/tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: From which folder do you run eslint to get this error?

Comment: @Baboo from the root folder

Comment: @Baboo
I run this:
`npx eslint -c cypress/.eslintrc.js cypress`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is, ESLint detects by default current working directory as the root folder. So this led ESLint to detect root tsconfig.json.
Problem solved by doing in `cypress/.eslintrc.js` file:

```
parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 12,
        project: './tsconfig.json',
        tsconfigRootDir: 'cypress',
        sourceType: 'module',
},
```

(could also solved by setting project value to `cypress/tsconfig.json`)

For more reference:
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/4732

Answer (score 0):

### For SvelteKit developers

Add this to your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "include": [
        "./.svelte-kit/ambient.d.ts",
        "./.svelte-kit/types/**/$types.d.ts",
        "./vite.config.ts",
        "./src/**/*.js",
        "./src/**/*.ts",
        "./src/**/*.svelte",
        "./tests/**/*.js",
        "./tests/**/*.ts",
        "./tests/**/*.svelte",

        "**/.*.cjs",
        "**/*.cjs",
        "**/*.js",
        "**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

Pay attention to paths, there is no typo.